# load different base map on highmap

Tags: dictionary, layer, radix

I implemented different trading data set for world map. There are quite bit business logics about how to show tool tip, axis colors etc.

Now client ask me implement similar function for USA base map with same business logics.

I wonder is there a better way to load different base map on highmap? by layer or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure thsis demo will help you
Here we can select different map regions on out demand.
WE actually need to update the mapData key on demand like

```
mapKey = Highcharts.map['custom/world-continents'];

series : [{
          data : data,
          mapData: mapKey,
        }]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/all-maps/

Following link might help you as well

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/chart/events-click-getcoordinates/